# PrimeNG Dialog prevent autofocus on first button

Tags: html, angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I want to prevent the autofocus on the first input element when open the PrimeNG dialog.

```
<p-dialog header="User Details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" 
   [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade"
   [modal]="true" (onAfterHide)="onDialogHide()">
   <p-button icon="fa fa-fw fa-minus"
              label="Delete" class="delete-button">
    </p-button>
</p-dialog>
```

Is there a possibility to prevent the autofocus?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker or share more code please ?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer but there is a `focusOnShow` attribute for p-dialog which defaults to `true`.  Set it to `false` will stop focusing on the first button. Not sure which version of PrimeNG this was introduced in.

Answer (score 1):

focusOnShow can be used only if you have p-dialog. If you are using dialog service then there is no possibility to remove autoFocus, or I just couldn't find.